# associate more than one subnets in route table subnet association using cloudformation yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I created the stack using amazon cloudformation in yaml.

•   VPC with 4 Subnets (2 Public and 2 Private).

•   Each public and private subnets were placed in the AZ ap-south-1a (1 
        public, 1 private and in ap-south-1b (1 public and 1 private).

•   Created Route Tables for public and private subnets.

•   Tried associating the the public subnets of 1a and 1b to the public RT 
        but it doesn't worked. but if i associate 1 subnet to this public rt 
        it does work.

How to associate multiple subnets to a route table using cloudformation (yaml)?

Thank in advance.

```
CFPublicRT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public RT
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
  CFPrivateRT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private RT
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
  routetablepublicsubnetassociation:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref CFPublicRT
        SubnetId: !Ref CFPublicSubnet1a
  routetableprivatesubnetassociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref CFPrivateRT
      SubnetId: !Ref CFPrivateSubnet1a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePublic
    SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePublic
    SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB
SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivate
    SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetC
SubnetDRouteTableAssociation:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTablePrivate
    SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetD
```